# Extract specific value from a filter-list (auto-complete field)

Tags: java, blackberry

in my application I'm trying to extract the values from a filter list (auto-complete field). 
In that field I have [ID, Name] ex [j342234, A,S]. I was able to retrieve the whole criteria by
doing this

```
Object Filterlistresult = fliterList.getCriteria();
```

but now I want to get extract  ID part only from that field. Any Ideas?

Thank you in advance.

```
// here I get the values from a web server and insert them to the work Vector
public void parseJSONResponceInWB(String jsonInStrFormat) {
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonInStrFormat);
        JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("transport");

        for (int i = 1; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject j = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            ID = j.getString("ID");
            Name = j.getString("Name");

            WBenchVector.addElement(ID + " " + Name);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// adding the values to the filter list
private void RequestAutoComplete() {
    String[] returnValues = new String[WBenchVector.size()];
    System.out.print(returnValues);
    for (int i = 0; i < WBenchVector.size(); i++) {
        returnValues[i] = (String) WBenchVector.elementAt(i);
    }
    autoCompleteField(returnValues);
}

// creating the filter list field
private void autoCompleteField(String[] returnValues) {
    filterLst = new BasicFilteredList();
    filterLst.addDataSet(ID, returnValues, "",
            BasicFilteredList.COMPARISON_IGNORE_CASE);

    autoFld.setFilteredList(filterLst);
}
```

Finally i'm getting what the user select using this

```
AutoFieldCriteria = filterLst.getCriteria();
```

Comment: Can you post the code you use to create `filterList` and add data to it?

Comment: Thank you so much Nate. I appreciate your help! I added the code to my message to make it more understandable. Waiting for your help. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Nate. I actually fixed the problem. 
I converted the filterField Object to String and then I looked for the index of the first space, and substring the first word

```
      Object AutoFieldCriteria = filterLst.getCriteria();
 String AutoFieldString = AutoFieldCriteria.toString();
 int spacePos = AutoFieldString.indexOf(" ");
 String AutoFieldFirstWord = AutoFieldString.substring(0,spacePos);
```

Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome.  You actually can, and should, **Accept** your own answer by clicking the "V" icon next to the answer.  That way, people know your problem has been solved, and you don't need more help with this question.

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot Nate :). I will do that.